# Spatialite 4.3 err: no such function: gpkgAddGeomtryColumn

Tags: spatialite, sqlite, geopackage

I'm opening a GeoPackage made by QGIS 2.18.17 then closing it and opening it with:

- spatialite_gui (spatialite lib loaded:4.3.0a)
- DB Browser (SELECT load_extension('mod_spatialite');)

Spatialite libs 4.3.0 are loaded. (I made a SELECT spatialite_version())

Creating my own table is OK but when I want to append a geometry column, the command fails with the sentence:

*no such function: gpkgAddGeomtryColumn:"SELECT gpkgAddGeomtryColumn('test','geom' ,'MULTIPOLYGON' ,1 ,0 ,3163);"*

This function is listed in [here](https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-4.3.0.html) in the section SQL functions implementing OGC GeoPackage compatibility

Does somebody knows why this function is not found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a typo in the documentation. The function name is `gpkgAddGeometryColumn` while the usage docs are (incorrectly)  `gpkgAddGeomtryColumn(...): void`.

In your usage, you're missing the `e`.